# play sound with audioplayers in silent mode flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

Is there a way to play sound with [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) when the device is in silent mode?
My phone is always is silent mode because I don't want it to vibrate or play any sound when I get notifications.
But I have some app on my phone which still get the play sounds, and that is OK and fine.

I was wondering if I can't do the same with `audioplayers` or any other package.

```
final AudioPlayer player;

void playNotificationSound() async {
 await player.setPlayerMode(PlayerMode.lowLatency);
 await player.play(AssetSource(audioFilePlath));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can change your code to use the `audioplayers` package for playing notification sounds:

```
void playNotificationSound() async {
  await player.setUrl(audioFilePath); // Use setUrl instead of setPlayerMode
  await player.play();
}
```

Make sure you've added the necessary permissions in your app's AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist files to allow audio playback. Doing this should help ensure that your app can play audio files without any issues.

Comment: Hi @WebDesk Solution. The sounds are playing already. My only problem is that there are not playing when the phone is in silent mode.

Comment: Okay, there seems to be some confusion on my end. Let me clarify and provide you with a solution.